# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I am getting an error like this all other pages working perfectly but getting error I have added new page in my website locally this is working

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error  Description: An application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on
>   the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>     </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>     </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```

Comment: please share the full exception details.

Comment: you get this in one page or all the page? Please punctuate properly and add more details.

Comment: i got this eeror only for one page i had just add new page in my application ad got error for only this page

Comment: Like Sajith asked please add exception details. Without exception details no one can help you.

Comment: Turn off customErrors so we can all find out what the real error is and then we can help. Or if you have any error logging mechanism in your site, it would be much better if you can get the error details from there.

Comment: Visit the page in local web browser, not remote one, to see the full error message

Comment: thank u for reply on local Web browser its working i got error  on remote browser

Comment: Please carefully *read* the message that the page is giving you - an error has occurred, but due to configuration settings, it's giving you no more information at this stage. It also tells you how to change the configuration so that more information is included. As it is, this error page could be the result of any of ~15 billion different errors, so we're not able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know what the error is, change your web.config file like so:

```
 <configuration>
     <system.web>
         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
     </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Basically, the error you're getting is telling you to do this so that you'll be able to see the actual error.

Warning: If your website is out there on the internet, then anyone who tries to view will see the exact error message. This may be a security problem, since it might enable people to see parts of your code or even configuration.